# Logout an user in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, logout

I'd like to know whether it's possible to logout an user in CakePHP.
I **don't** want to logout the current user, but to end the session of a selected user.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it isn't possible. CakePHP at least doesn't have some internal ways to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you could do a simple conditional check:

With authsome component:

```
if (Authsome::get('User.id') == $idOfUserYouWantToLogout){
    Authsome::logout();
}
```

Note: you could of course use $this->Authsome->get('User.id') and $this->Authsome->logout() if you wanted.

With normal auth component:

```
if ($this->Auth->get('id') == $idOfUserYouWantToLogout){
$this->Auth->logout();
}
```

This is kind of a work-around, because it will log out the current user, but only if they are the user that you want logged out.

Comment: This isn't what I was looking for, because I want to logout some user from a kind of ‘control panel’, in order to force them to login again. By the way I don't need this anymore, thank you anyway! :)